# Assigning Random Number to Array of Objects

Tags: java, class

I am trying to assign a random number to an array of objects and I am trying to assign it to a variable called score. My main class code is below:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bands[] bands = new Bands[5];        
    bands[0] = new Bands("Joe", "Rick", "Nick", "Dalton", "Doylestown, PA", "RockOn", 4000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[1] = new Bands("Luke", "Bill", "Ian", "Matt", "State College, PA", "Blink182", 3500.50 , "Alternative");
    bands[2] = new Bands("Corey", "Noah", "Jon", "Kaleb", "Philadelphia, PA", "Rise Against", 10000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[3] = new Bands("Jake", "Joey", "Mike", "Mac", "New York, NY", "Thousand Foot Krutch", 2000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[4] = new Bands("Bob", "Jeff", "Dom", "Mark", "King of Prussia, PA", "Skillet", 5500.50 , "Rock");

    int score = compete(score);        
}    
}
```

And then my Bands class code is located below. I am having trouble getting it to work properly:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Bands {

private String singerName;
private String guitarName;
private String bassistName;
private String drummerName;
private String Hometown;
private String bandName;
private double income;
private String genre;
private int score;

public Bands(String singerName, String guitarName, String bassistName, String drummerName, String Hometown, String bandName, double income, String genre)
{
    this.singerName = singerName;
    this.guitarName = guitarName;
    this.bassistName = bassistName;
    this.drummerName = drummerName;
    this.bandName = bandName;
    this.Hometown = Hometown;
    this.income = income;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.score = -1;
}

public int compete()
{     
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.score = rand.nextInt(20);

    return score;
}

public String getInfo()
{
    String bandInfo = "Band: " + this.bandName + ", Singer: " + this.singerName + ", Guitarist: " + this.guitarName + ", Bassist: " + this.bassistName + 
                      ", Drummer: " + this.drummerName + ", Hometown: " + this.Hometown + ", Income: " + this.income + ", Genre: " + 
                      this.genre + ", Final Score: " + this.score;

    return bandInfo;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: `I am having trouble getting it to work properly:` what error do you get ? You need to describe your problem clearly

Comment: the problem that i am having is assigning a random score to the score variable. my main class code does not work and the problem is the "int score" line of code

Comment: Are you trying to do `for (Band b : bands) b.compete();` ?

Comment: You can't use a variable as you define it and you can't call a method you haven't defined.

Comment: This line `int score = compete(score);` doesn't make any sense.  `compete` is a function of a `Band`.  So to call `compete` on say the first band you have to do this `bands[0].compete();`  Also, compete doesn't take any arguments so why are you passing an argument of `score` in your method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Bands` have method compete that not take any parameter and in your main method you call a method compete that take a score :

```
int score = compete(score);
```

So i assume that you want to call your compete method that exist in another class so to solve this issue yo should :

1. Create setter of your attribute score in Bands class
2. Create a new Bands object :
3. Set the Score
4. Call your compete method

```
    Bands b = new Bands();
    b.setScore(score);
    int score = b.compete();
```

Or

change the compete method to take an attribute score

```
public int compete(int score){     
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.score = rand.nextInt(20);
    return score;
}
```